# Remove an Item from the shopping cart on dropdown change event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am building an e-commence system where a user can select an item from the **category** dropdown list.
I want the user to add only one item from each **category** and when they change the item from that category it must remove the one that already exist in the cart. Every categories items have the same item ID so that the user cannot add two or more items from the same category.

I can add the items to the shopping cart, but i'm struggling to make sure that if the item from the same category already exists in the cart it must be deleted first. **E.g** if a user want to add a Sony Chase to cart and an LG Chase is already in the cart, the LG chase must be replaced by the Sony because they belong to the same Category **Chassis**.  I don't know if i'm clear

```
<form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1"/>
    <table>
    <tr><td width="180">
<select name="chasis" id="chasis" onChange="grabInfo(this.value)" class="styled-select">
    <option value="">-- Select Chasis --</option>
    <?php 
            $queryChasis = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chasis");     

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryChasis))
            {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['ItemID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['CName']; ?></option>
            <?php
            } 
            ?>
      </select>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </fieldset>
 </form>


<!-- Ajax Passing the ID -->
function grabInfo(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfoChasis.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page.
This is where i try to remove the existing item from the same category

```
if (isset($_GET["q"])) {
$pid = $_GET["q"];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;
// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
    // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
} else {
    // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
              if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {

                  // That item is in cart already so let's remove
                  $key_to_remove = $pid;
                if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
                } else {
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$pid"]);
                    sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
                }
                  $wasFound = true;
              } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
       } // close foreach loop
       if ($wasFound == false) {
           array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
       }
}
}
```

render the cart for the user to view on the page

```
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
$cartOutput .= "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
}
else
{
$i = 0; 
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
    $i++;
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chasis WHERE ID='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $product_name = $row["CName"];
        $price = $row["Price"];
    }
    $cartTotal = $price + $cartTotal;
    /*$cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item id: ".$each_item['item_id']."<br/>";
    $cartOutput .= "Quantity: ".$each_item['quantity']."<br/>";*/
    $cartOutput .= "<tr><td>".$product_name."</td>";
    $cartOutput .= "<td>".$price."</td></tr>";
}
//total price
$cartTotal = $cartTotal;
}
echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
<tr bgcolor="#ccffcc"><td width="220">Item Name</td>
<td width="120">Price</td></tr>';
echo $cartOutput;
echo '</table>';

echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
<tr align="right"><td width="220"><strong>Total Price:</strong></td>
<td width="120">'.$cartTotal.'</td></tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: you want php,javascript

Comment: I'm developing in PHP, and using Ajax and JQuery to make sure that the page does not load every time the user process the Cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed 3 eCommerce application already and i solved these kind of problems in a standard manner.

1. First of all, you need to save the `Category ID` along with the `Product ID` of any product added in the cart. Now lets come to your problem. You want to add only one item per Category for any user right? Suppose, i have several products under JUICE category. If `Category ID` for JUICE is 4 for example, then all products under JUICE category will have 4 as their `Category ID`.

What you can do is, when an user selects a product from dropdown, you pass the `Product ID` and `Category ID` using ajax in the ajax page. Please try to using session array as using session as array is not professional approach and if your array it too long, it can effect the loading speed. So what you can do is, after passing `Product ID` and `Category ID`, you can check the cart using `SELECT` query to find if same category product already exist in the table. If so, then run a `DELETE` query to delete the product and then run a `INSERT` query to insert new product. Otherwise you can add the new product using `INSERT` query directly.

If you need to know more details like queries you need to deal with, please let me know. I will try to help you out as much as possible.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your input and guidance William. I have managed to get the shopping cart working the way you advised me, I can change all the products under each category dynamically. Now the problem i'm facing is i'm sorting the Cart Array every time i change the products which makes that product to be the last product to be added on the shopping cart. Is the a way i can delete and insert a new product on the cart without re-sorting the Cart array?

Comment: //if cart has more than 1 items
unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]); sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
       array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("category_id" => $cid,"item_id" => $pid, "table" => $table));

Comment: Hello amu, did my suggestion helped you to solve the problem?? Let me know.

Comment: Yes, it did solve my problem. now the problem is i'm sorting the array every time after i changed an item from Shopping Cart. this makes the item being changed to be the last on the shopping cart list. is the any solution to this?

Comment: Can u check it by using `ORDER BY fieldname` in your sql statement? Let me know.

Comment: Hi William. Sorry for replying late. i tried the ORDER but it cunt seem to work. Please download the project on this link: http://www.amukelanin.co.za/portfolio.php da project name is "SHOP-CART". maybe you can help me figure out the problem. Thank you!